# Image uploading from android to PHP server using retrofit

Tags: java, php, android, json, retrofit2

I am uploading image to server using retrofit. I am encoding image to bitmap and then convert bitmap to string and passing string to PHP. On PHP side I decode image again and then save to server folder.
It works perfectly if I compress image quality to 30 but app crashes and shows null pointer if I set image quality to 100.

Here is my Code:

ResultActivity:

```
if (requestCode == 1 && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, 
filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            // photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);


            profile_photo = 
ImageUtils.getInstant().getCompressedBitmap(picturePath);
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(this, profile_photo);
            cursor.close();
            profile_image.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(tempUri)
                    .resize(150, 150)
                    .into(profile_image);
            profile_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            profile_image.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            //Bitmap profile_photo = ((BitmapDrawable) 
profile_image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            upload_profileimage();

            b.dismiss();

        }
```

Bitmap to string:

```
public String BitmapTOString(Bitmap bitmap) {

    Bitmap bm = bitmap;
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
    String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imgString;


}
```

Retrofit API call:

```
call = user_profileimge_interface.profileImage_uplaod(BitmapTOString(profile_photo), user_id);
```

PHP Code:

```
$data = $baseurl.'user_profile_pictures/'.$user_id.".JPEG";
file_put_contents($data, base64_decode($profile_picture));
echo json_encode(Array('message' => "image inserted"));
```

API interface:

```
@POST("update_profilepic.php")
Call<Profile_Image_updateJson> profileImage_uplaod(@Query("profile_picture") String profileImage,
                                                   @Query("user_id") String user_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest sending bitmap as binary data rather than converting to/from string. For example:

```
@POST
Call<Profile_Image_updateJson> profileImage_uplaod(@Query("user_id") String user_id, @Body RequestBody body);
```

and then something like:

```
requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), imageBytes)
call = user_profileimge_interface.profileImage_uplaod(user_id, requestBody);
```

Comment: thanks @John. Please can you add some code for how to get this in php and save it to server folder?

Comment: @AsifUllah I'm not really famiiar with PHP but assume there must be pretty standard way of doing this.  From quick google I see good few articles (though mostly related to using `Multipart` Posts which is also another approach you can take.

Comment: @AsifUllah follow John's suggestion and refer this PHP's official [documentation for uploading files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try to Perform `BitmaptoString()` operation in a separate thread, away from the Main UI Thread.

As processing bitmap is too costly if you perform it in the Main UI Thread, the App might crash. Also, you can use `Asynctask` or Any Background Process to perform costly functions and avoid any costly operations in Main Thread.